# Django query hitting the db for every iteration

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a some **model.py** like so:

```
class Muestraonline(models.Model):
    accessionnumber = models.ForeignKey(Muestra, related_name='online_accessionnumber')
    muestraid = models.ForeignKey(Muestra)
    taxonid = models.ForeignKey(Taxon, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Muestra(models.Model):
    muestraid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='MuestraID') # Field name made lowercase.
    latitudedecimal = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6, null=True, max_digits=20, db_column='LatitudeDecimal', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    longitudedecimal = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6, null=True, max_digits=20, db_column='LongitudeDecimal', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    ...
```

And my **view.py** I want to get the unique specimen and find all specimens which share that taxonid. For the related specimens I just need the lat/long info:

```
def specimen_detail(request, accession_number=None, specimen_id=None):
    specimen = Muestraonline.objects.get(accessionnumber=accession_number, muestraid=specimen_id)
    related_specimens = Muestraonline.objects.filter(taxonid=specimen.taxonid).exclude(id=specimen.id)

    # create array for the related specimen points 
    related_coords = []
    # loop through results and populate array
    for relative in related_specimens:
        latlon = (format(relative.muestraid.latitudedecimal), format(relative.muestraid.longitudedecimal))
        related_coords.append(latlon) 
    related_coords = simplejson.dumps(related_coords)
```

But when I loop through `related_specimens` it ends up hitting the db once for each `relative`. Shouldn't I be able to get the `latitudedecimal` and `longitudedecimal` values in the format I need with only one extra db query? I know I missing something very basic in my approach here, just not sure of the best way to get this done.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in your QuerySet:

```
related_specimens = Muestraonline.objects.filter(taxonid=specimen.taxonid).exclude(id=specimen.id).select_related('muestraid')
```

That will join your `Muestraonline` model to `Muestra` behind the scenes and each `Muestraonline` instance returned by the QuerySet will also contain a cached instance of `Muestra`.

Comment: Totally correct! I completely forgot about `select_related` - has been a while since I have had call to use it. Thankyou.