# Django query hitting db more than expected

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a **model.py** like so:

```
class Muestraonline(models.Model):
    accessionnumber = models.ForeignKey(Muestra, related_name='online_accessionnumber')
    muestraid = models.ForeignKey(Muestra)
    taxonid = models.ForeignKey(Taxon, null=True, blank=True)
    collectedby = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, blank=True)
    locality = models.ForeignKey(Localitymayor, null=True, blank=True)
```

in my **views.py:**

```
def search(request):
    ...
        if genus:
           q &= Q(taxonid__genus__icontains = genus)
        if species:
           q &= (Q(taxonid__specificepithet__icontains = species | Q(taxonid__infraspecificepithet__icontains = species ))) 
        if island_group:
           q &= Q(locality__islandgroup__icontains = island_group)
        if island_name:
           q &= Q(locality__islandname__icontains = island_name)
        if collection_acronym:
           q &= Q(muestraid__collectionid__collectioncode__icontains = collection_acronym)
        if accession_number:
           q &= Q(muestraid__accessionnumber = accession_number)
        if last_name:
           q &= Q(collectedby__verbatimname__icontains = last_name)
        if collection_number:
           q &= Q(muestraid__collectionnumber = collection_number)

        query_set = Muestraonline.objects.filter(q).order_by('taxonid__genus', 'taxonid__specificepithet', 'muestraid') 

        query_set = list(query_set)
```

and in my **template** I do something like so:

```
{% for specimen in items.object_list %}
 {{ specimen.taxonid.genus }} -- {{ specimen.taxonid.specificepithet }}
 {{ specimen.muestraid_id }}
 {{ specimen.accessionnumber_id }}
 {{ specimen.muestraid.localitymayorid.islandname }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I look at the results using django debug toolbar, I see that the initial search query is pretty heavy on the db, but I guess unavoidable given the structure (which will not change). However, when I iterate in the template each object also makes a query to get the `taxon` and `locality` data.

I thought the use of `select_related()` would avoid this, but it actually slows the request down (by adding a bunch of joins on the initial query), and the total number of queries stays the same.

My question is: how can I minimize the hits to the db? For example, can I get the query set to evaluate once and then pull my results from this during iteration in the template? As you can see, I already tried to cast `query_set` as a list but that makes no difference.

Any guidance here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't post a new question; unaccept the answer on [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255011/django-query-hitting-the-db-for-every-iteration) and add details about how this is slower.

Comment: If `items` is a queryset, that's where it being evaluated.

Comment: Actually this is a slightly different query for another view. What I am looking for is some advice specifically on the db interaction for this query. True, it is related but I feel it is a separate, and more general question.

Comment: `items` is the iterable object used in the pagination (not shown).

Comment: You're probably not showing us everything – what is this `specimen.muestraid.localitymayorid`? Is that a `ForeignKey` in `Muestra` to `Localitymayor`?

Comment: yes, there are several `ForeignKey` relationships which are followed. As I mentioned though, using `select_related` did not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to try telling `select_related` which exact relationships to follow. The fact that adding `select_related` made the query too slow might be because it was following unneeded relationships. Try the following:

```
query_set = Muestraonline.objects.filter(q).order_by('taxonid__genus', 'taxonid__specificepithet', 'muestraid').select_related('taxonid', 'muestraid__localitymayorid')
```

I find it hard to believe that after adding `select_related` to your query it was still hitting the database for each instance – are you sure you are evaluating the right QuerySet?

Also, converting the QuerySet to a list before feeding it to a paginator is not the best idea – it ends up fetching everything from the database and then throwing most of it away since you are displaying only a small subset. If you feed a QuerySet directly into paginator, it limits the QuerySet itself to fetch only the items you want.